# FIlling a pool - Related rates

Tags: calculus, derivatives

**Problem**

A swimming pool is

- 25 meters long
- 10 meters wide
- 1 meter deep in one end
- 6 meters deep in the other end

The bottom of the pool is linearly slanted.

The pool is filled with water at a rate of 2000 liters/minute.

How fast does the water level rise at the point in time when the depth of the water is 3 meters?

**My work**

I have drawn a figure, as I often do.

[image]

Since we're dealing with a volume of water, I thought I might start with expressing the volume of the water as a function of the distances of the body of water.

Since the water will be the area of the right triangle, times the width of the pool, I have $$V = \frac12 g h w$$ where $g$ is the horizontal edge of the triangle, $h$ is the current depth of the water, and $w$ is the width of the pool.

Knowing that $h = 3$ and $w = 10$ gives me $V = 15g$.

At this point, I'm stuck, and would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 1):

There are $1000$ liters in a cubic meter, so the fill rate is $2$ m$^3$/min.  The slope of the bottom of the pool is $0.2$ (or $-0.2$, depending on your point of view).  So when the water is $3$ m deep at the deep end, the horizontal water surface is $15$ m long.  Since the pool is $10$ m wide, the surface area at that point is $150$ m.

Instantaneously, then, since you are only interested in first-order changes in water level, you can just pretend the pool has a surface area of $150$ m.  How fast does the water level increase if you are pouring water in at $2$ m$^3$/min?

Answer (score 0):

Find an expression for the Volume in terms of the height. Using similar triangles, you can show that the area of the triangle when the height reaches $h$, the length is $5h$ so that the volume is $V(h) = 50 h^2$. It should now be easy for you to calculate $\frac{dV}{dh}$ and find the value you desire.